# Canary with istio, what happen if app backend service is down/slow

Tags: istio, canary

> App A is a Php application, service B is elasticsearch.
>
> A is deployed via istio, with canary pattern.
>
> A'canary and A'current use the same B service.

If B is getting slow or down, A'canary and A'current will throw same errors, what happen at this moment?

1. A'canary is disabled and 100% of traffic go to A'current
2. istio can detect the trouble is not app related, and still route some traffic to canary

Answer (score 0):

Istio offers [canary](https://istio.io/latest/blog/2017/0.1-canary/) versions for deployments as a percentage-based traffic splitting. Afaik istio will keep routing traffic as usual by default.

For simple summary and example of canary deployment check this [guide](https://www.istiobyexample.dev/canary).

If you wish to have more sophisticated and dynamic management of canary deployments that relies on heath checks and metrics You should consider using something like [Flagger](https://docs.flagger.app/) which is compatible with istio.